# Making A Game Manager C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make a game manager like steam (without the downloads just something that lists your games) in C#?

I'm just not sure what the .NET framework can do.

Comment: -1 This question is not related to game development.

Comment: It doesn't depend on what .Net framework can do; depends on what you could do with .net framework; and that further depends on your expertise with .net technologies and C#.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course it's possible. You can do just as much with C# as you can do with any other language (which is just about anything).

Most programming languages you find will be [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), which effectively means you can always do with one what you can do with another. The only real difference is the way you can approach those problems with the given language, and what libraries are available. Since C# and the .NET framework have a tremendous variety of libraries available, there are not many limits there.